# Does one have to present a paper version of one's e-visa when entering Myanmar with an e-visa, or is showing it on a phone/tablet/laptop accepted?

Tags: visas, paperwork, e-visas, myanmar

E-visas for Myanmar state:

> You are required to bring this Visa Approval Letter with you as Ministry of Labour, Immigration and Population requires you to produce it for verification when you arrive in Myanmar.

Does one have to present a paper version (i.e., printed) of one's e-visa when entering Myanmar with an e-visa, or is showing the e-visa on a phone/tablet/laptop accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a print out for the most cases. Its easier to print beforehand than do it in an overpriced facility at an Airport when a gate agent or immigration ask for a print copy.

Comment: Thanks, in which case(s) do one have to print? Printing a document can be time-consuming, so that would rather do it only if required.

Comment: I don't have a specific example in case of Myanmar.

For Vietnam, Malaysia and Singapore - I had to show the printouts. Mobile copy was not acceptable. So, its a safe bet to print it beforehand.